# how to close all FileStreams related to specific file?

Tags: c#, filestream

I got a file stream:

```
tempOutputStream = new FileStream(sTempFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Once the file is created you can create additional FileStreams to read/write `tempOutputStream`.
Is there a way to close all of them not having a ref to each stream obj? Or at least for the first one that creates the stream.

the problem is that I'd like to delete the file but one of the streams is not closed so I got an exception in `File.Delete`...

Thank you.

Regards,
Leonid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You need to fix your code and ensure that all streams are closed when you finish using them.
Use the `using` statement.

Comment: cant use "using" -  i create stream in one place then many classes do smth with it in its methods... lots of old code :(

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

- extend the FileStream class, or create your Stream derivation
- in it, add method something like `GetNewStream()`
- that method can return new stream, and write its reference to some internal `List<Stream>`
- override `Close()`, and `Close()` each stream from the list
- override `Dispose()`, and `Dispose()` each stream from the list

That way you'll hide your functionality where it should be, away from you in the main line of code.

Another, to prevent hard refactoring:

- my guess is that you have something like `Stream s=originalStream.GetStream();` in your code (I don't know by heart how the stream is duplicated...)
- create a singleton, that will contain `Map<Stream, list<Stream>>` and several methods:

  - `RegisterStreamChild(Stream Parent, Stream Child);`
  - `CloseAllChildSteams(Stream Parent)`
- implement those methods using the Map<> contained in the singleton
- search your code for occurrences of stream duplication.  Use first method to register new stream
- search your code for occurrences of stream closing.  Use second method to close all child streams

Comment: i was thinking of the similar solution but this make me do lots of refactoring... Anyway thanks!

Comment: @Leonid: refactoring, if done properly, is something that will bring you much benefit in the long run.  I'll propose alternative solution in the answer...